# Add variables whilst ignoring NA`s using transform function

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a large number of variables. I am creating new variables by adding together some of the old ones. The code I am using to do so is:

```
name_of_data_frame<- transform(name_of_data_frame, new_variable=var1+var2 +....)
```

When transform comes across a NA in one of the observations, it returns "NA" in the new variable, even if some of the other variables it was adding were not NA.

e.g. if `var1= 4`, `var2=3`, `var3=NA`, then using `transform`, if I did `var1+var2+var3` it would give out `NA`, whereas I would like it to give me 7.

I don't want to recode my `NA`s to zero within the data frame, as I may need to refer back to the `NA`s later, so don't want to confuse the `NA`s with the observations which were genuinely `0`.

Any help on how to get around R treating `NA`s in the way described above with the transform function would be great (or if there are alternative functions to use, that would be great also).

Please note that I am not always just summing variables that are next to each other, I am also often dividing variables, multiplying, subtracting etc.

Comment: Do you want the `NA`s to always behave like zero? For example, if you are multiplying var1 x var2 x var3 using your example, do you want that to be 0 or perhaps 4x3?

Comment: @seancarmody I would preferably then want it to be 4x3.

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify--pretty much in all cases (adding, dividing, multiplying, subtracting, and whatever else), your preference is going to be to drop `NA`s before doing your calculations. Is that correct?

Comment: That seems dangerous in its generality.

Comment: @mrdwab yes that is correct. I will be doing some data imputation for most variables to sort out some of the NA`s, but that`s not possible with all of them, in which case I am wanting to ignore them, but not recode them to zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first instinct was to suggest to use `sum()` since then you can use the `na.rm` argument.  However, this doesn't work, since `sum()` reduces it arguments to a single scalar value, not a vector.

This means you need to write a `parallel sum` function. Let's call this `psum()`, similar to the base R function `pmin()` or `pmax()`:

```
psum <- function(..., na.rm=FALSE) { 
  x <- list(...)
  rowSums(matrix(unlist(x), ncol=length(x)), na.rm=na.rm)
}
```

---

Now set up some data and use `psum()` to get the desired vector:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3, NA),
  y = c(NA, 4, 5, NA))

transform(dat, new=psum(x, y, na.rm=TRUE))
   x  y new
1  1 NA   1
2  2  4   6
3  3  5   8
4 NA NA   0
```

---

Similarly, you can define a `parallel product`, or `pprod()` like this:

```
pprod <- function(..., na.rm=FALSE) { 
  x <- list(...)
  m <- matrix(unlist(x), ncol=length(x))
  apply(m, 1, prod, na.rm=TRUE)
} 

transform(dat, new=pprod(x, y, na.rm=TRUE))
   x  y new
1  1 NA   1
2  2  4   8
3  3  5  15
4 NA NA   1
```

---

This example of `pprod` provides a general template for what you want to do: Create a function that uses `apply()` to summarize a matrix of input into the desired vector.

Comment: Nice. I have used `apply` but have not used `transform` so I hadn't even checked to see what `sum` was doing in this case with an "extended" dataset. Oops! Deleting some of my comments now ;-), and +1, of course.

Comment: Thanks!
Although, if I had 3 columns, for example x, y, and z, for which I wanted to do the following: (x+y)/z, how could I go about that? As the above seems to do multiply and summing seperately?

Comment: @TimothyAlston In that case you need to write a custom function that does that. Alternatively, don't use transform.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rowSums` and `prod` could help you out.

```
set.seed(007) # Generating some data
DF <- data.frame(V1=sample(c(50,NA,36,24,80, NA), 15, replace=TRUE),
                 V2=sample(c(70,40,NA,25,100, NA), 15, replace=TRUE),
                 V3=sample(c(20,26,34,15,78,40), 15, replace=TRUE))

transform(DF, Sum=rowSums(DF, na.rm=TRUE)) # Sum (a vector of values)
transform(DF, Prod=apply(DF, 1, FUN=prod, na.rm=TRUE)) # Prod (a vector of values)

# Defining a function for substracting (resta, in spanish :D)
resta <- function(x) Reduce(function(a,b) a-b,  x <- x[!is.na(x)])
transform(DF, Substracting=apply(DF, 1, resta))

# Defining a function for dividing 
div <- function(x) Reduce(function(a,b) a/b,  x <- x[!is.na(x)])
transform(DF, Divsion=apply(DF, 1, div))
```