# manipulate a data frame with values as strings

Tags: r

I asked a question which seems to be very difficult to solve. I have been busy with it for few days already. I try to break down the questions to smaller questions so that I might get some help. The original question is here [extract information from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726892/extract-information-from-a-data-frame)

I have a data frame like below

```
df<- structure(list(s1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("3-4", "4-1", "5-4"
    ), class = "factor"), s2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2-4", "3-15", 
    "7-16"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("s1", "s2"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L), class = "data.frame")
Looks like below
```

In this example I have two columns but the solution should not specific to only two columns

```
> df
#   s1         s2
#1 3-4        2-4
#2 4-1        3-15
#3 5-4        7-16
```

I want to count how many times a string after - is repeated and how many times they appear in each column

Lets say if I look at the first column, I see 4, 1, 4 and second column I see 4, 15 and 16 , so I will have 3 times 4 is repeated , once 1 and once 15 and once 16

M  repeated 
4   3
1   1
15  1
16  1

If I look at which columns they come from these strings 
4 comes two times from column 1 and once from column 2 
1 comes once from first column (s1)
15 comes once from column (s2)
comes once from second column (s2)

so I will have the output like this

```
M    repeated  COL1  COL2
4     3         2      1
1     1         1      -
15    1         -      1
16    1         -      1
```

what I was thinking ? thanks to @Arkun, I can melt the df

```
M1 <- melt(df, id.var=NULL)
```

The output will be like this

```
>M1
   #  variable value
   # 1       s1   3-4
   # 2       s1   4-1
   # 3       s1   5-4
   # 4       s2   2-4
   # 5       s2  3-15
   # 6       s2  7-16
```

Then I split the values based on the hyphen using below

```
lst <- setNames(strsplit(M1$value, "-"), M1$variable)
```

now I have the following

```
>lst
#$s1
#[1] "3" "4"
#$s1
#[1] "4" "1"
#$s1
#[1] "5" "4"
#$s2
#[1] "2" "4"
#$s2
#[1] "3"  "15"
#$s2
#[1] "7"  "16"
```

Then I don't know how to get further

Comment: If you load data.table, then `setDT(M1)[, c("pre","suff") := tstrsplit(value,"-")]; M1[, table(suff,variable)]`. Your "repeated" column is just the sum of the others and can be constructed afterwards.

Comment: @Frank that is amazing , one part is solved without any loop :-) , please make it as an answer so I can somehow appreciate your comment. Also if it is possible, can you have a look at the original question? I believe you can help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by @akrun, "melting" the data and splitting on `"-"` is a good start:

```
library(data.table)

m = setDT(melt(df, id.var=NULL))
m[, c("pre","suff") := tstrsplit(value, "-", type.convert=TRUE)]
```

Then you can summarize the data by tabulating:

```
m[, table(suff, variable)]

#     variable
# suff s1 s2
#   1   1  0
#   4   2  1
#   15  0  1
#   16  0  1
```

More generally, you can group by values of the suffix and construct summary stats:

```
summ = m[, .(
  N   = .N,
  pre = paste(sort(unique(pre)), collapse=",")
), keyby=.(suff, variable)]

#    suff variable N pre
# 1:    1       s1 1   4
# 2:    4       s1 2 3,5
# 3:    4       s2 1   2
# 4:   15       s2 1   3
# 5:   16       s2 1   7
```

To put the variables in their own columns again...

```
dcast(summ, suff~variable, value.var=c("N","pre"))

#    suff N_s1 N_s2 pre_s1 pre_s2
# 1:    1    1   NA      4     NA
# 2:    4    2    1    3,5      2
# 3:   15   NA    1     NA      3
# 4:   16   NA    1     NA      7
```

Check out the [introductory materials for the data.table package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for more on how this works and what else you can do.

Comment: I liked and accepted your solution. I learned from it and I appreciate it very much . thanks bro

Comment: @Frank Good post.  Plus one.

Comment: @Mol Maybe it will work if you do `m = setDT(melt(df, id.var=NULL))[value != ""]`. Beyond that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Mol It does work for me.  Can you check the `str(df)`

Comment: @Mol I tried reading it `df <- read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/d51ad485c7a7b5d04b67/raw/9aea92f372b7a5e8ffd152689e0bb2b071c3d6f7/df.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  If you don't want the blanks, and NA's you can remove it.