# Sum two dataframes with NA values and factors

Tags: r

I'm trying to sum two dataframes containing NA values and factor variables. The values should be summed cell by cell, only for non-factor variables, and ignoring NAs.

As an example, the dataframes I'm handling are as the following two:

```
data1 <- data.frame(NAMES=c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
                X1=c(1, NA, 3),
                X2 = c(10, 11, 12))
data2 <- data.frame(NAMES=c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
                X1=c(4,NA,6),
                X2 = c(NA, 11, 12))
```

If I use the function `sum (..., na.rm=TRUE)`, I don't get a dataframe as result. I'm expecting something as the output returned by using the operator `+`. That is, a single dataframe with the same number of rows and columns, but where each cell is the result of adding the cells in the same coordinates of the addend dataframes. However, NAs and factors need to be ignored, like:

```
  NAMES X1 X2
1    name1  5 10
2    name2 NA 22
3    name3  9 24
```

is that possible?

Comment: If you ignore `NA` values, row 2 of `X1` will give zero, that's the behaviour of `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`. If you use `+` how do "ignore NAs"? Can you be more clear, please?

Comment: The `+` operator let you do the sum of two dataframes cell by cell in a straightforward way, but if just one (or more) of the addends is a NA value then the result is NA, even if there exits non-NA values in one of  the dataframes. O want to avoid that behaviour

Comment: Got it. See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add variables whilst ignoring NA\`s using transform function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139431/add-variables-whilst-ignoring-nas-using-transform-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Base R` Version:

```
library(dplyr) # only for pipe operator
rbind(data1, data2) %>%
  split(.$NAMES) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(NAMES = unique(x$NAMES),as.list(colSums(x[,-1]))) 
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

#       NAMES X1 X2
# name1 name1  5 NA
# name2 name2 NA 22
# name3 name3  9 24
```

Notice that NAMES now also appears as rownames. This is because `split` outputs a named list. You can either keep the rownames and remove `NAMES = unique(x$NAMES)`, or add an `unname()` pipe after `split`:

```
rbind(data1, data2) %>%
  split(.$NAMES) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(as.list(colSums(x[,-1]))) 
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

#       X1 X2
# name1  5 NA
# name2 NA 22
# name3  9 24

rbind(data1, data2) %>%
  split(.$NAMES) %>%
  unname() %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(NAMES = unique(x$NAMES),as.list(colSums(x[,-1]))) 
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

#   NAMES X1 X2
# 1 name1  5 NA
# 2 name2 NA 22
# 3 name3  9 24
```

To treat NA's as zeros, just add `na.rm = TRUE` to `colSums`:

```
rbind(data1, data2) %>%
  split(.$NAMES) %>%
  unname() %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(NAMES = unique(x$NAMES),as.list(colSums(x[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))) 
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)

#   NAMES X1 X2
# 1 name1  5 10
# 2 name2  0 22
# 3 name3  9 24
```

### `dplyr` + `purrr` Version:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

list(data1, data2) %>%
  reduce(function(x, y) cbind(NAMES = x$NAMES, x[,-1] + y[-1]))
```

Result:

```
  NAMES X1 X2
1 name1  5 NA
2 name2 NA 22
3 name3  9 24
```

To treat NA's as zero:

```
list(data1, data2) %>%
  map(function(x){
    modify_if(x, is.numeric, function(y) ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y))
  }) %>% 
  reduce(function(x, y) cbind(NAMES = x$NAMES, x[,-1] + y[-1]))
```

Result:

```
  NAMES X1 X2
1 name1  5 10
2 name2  0 22
3 name3  9 24
```

**Important Note:**

Replacing NA's with zeros is often a bad idea since they mean different things. NA could mean that the data is missing, not necessarily zero, so replacing all NA's with zeros could bias your results. Please only do it if you are sure that NA's mean zero in the context of your data.

**Additional Notes:**

1. Both `map` and `modify_if` are from the `purrr` package. `map` applies a function to each element of a list and always returns a list. `modify` does the same except that it returns the same type as the input.
2. `modify_if` only "maps" the elements that satisfy a condition.
3. In the first pipe, I used `map` to "map" each element of `list(data1, data2)` with the `modify_if` function, while `modify_if` replaces NA's with zeros for each numeric column only. This way I can use the `+` operator in the next pipe without worrying about NA's.
4. `reduce` does matrix addition on `data1` and `data2`, then `cbind`s it with `NAMES` column from `data1`.

Comment: Very nice option, thank you very much!, and thank you again for the additional notes

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)

data1 <- data.table(NAMES = c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
                    X1 = c(1, NA, 3),
                    X2 = c(10, 11, 12))

data2 <- data.table(NAMES = c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
                    X1 = c(4, NA, 6),
                    X2 = c(NA, 11, 12))

dat <- rbind(data1, data2)
dat[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T), keyby = "NAMES", .SDcols = c("X1", "X2")]
```

Please not the result is not precisely the same as you have shown in the question. Hope it is still useful.

```
> dat[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T), keyby = "NAMES", .SDcols = c("X1", "X2")]
   NAMES X1 X2
1: name1  5 10
2: name2  0 22
3: name3  9 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
as.data.frame(
    mapply(function(x, y)
        if(is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y))
            ifelse(is.na(y), x, x + y)
        else x,
        data1, data2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Output:

```
  NAMES X1 X2
1 name1  5 10
2 name2 NA 22
3 name3  9 24
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using base R only.

```
icol <- which(!(sapply(data1, is.factor) | sapply(data2, is.factor)))
result <- sapply(icol, function(i) rowSums(cbind(data1[i], data2[i]), na.rm = TRUE))
result <- cbind(data1[1], result)
is.na(result[icol]) <- is.na(data1[icol]) & is.na(data2[icol])
result
#  NAMES X1 X2
#1 name1  5 10
#2 name2 NA 22
#3 name3  9 24
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Error in rowSums(cbind(data1[i], data2[i]), na.rm = TRUE) :   'x' must be numeric` error when I run the second row of commands, why can it be?

Comment: @EuGENE I've tested it again, this time in a clean R session and there was no error. I cannot reproduce the problem. Before running the second line of commands, can you check the value of `icol`? It should be a named vector with names `X1 X2` and values `2 3`.

Comment: Well, it seems that now I'm not getting that error (don't know why). And I'm getting exactly the output I wanted, thank you very much!!